# How to fix a cross-thread exception in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, timer

I'm trying to use System.Timers.Timer on a UI control.

The error:
System.Timers.Timer "Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'txtOutput' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on."

My code is the following:

```
System.Timers.Timer timeRandomEvent = new System.Timers.Timer(10 * 1000); 

// timer for random events  
timeRandomEvent.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(timeRandomEvent_Elapsed);
timeRandomEvent.Start();

void timeRandomEvent_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e) 
{
    wl("Adding some text to a text box.");   // Exception occurs here
}
```

Is there a way to allow it, or another alternative that's hopefully easy?

Comment: Could you just use `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` instead?

Comment: @hatchet Although that seems to be the natural choice for WinForms, `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` is actually less accurate than `System.Timers.Timer` ([limited to accuracy of 55 milliseconds](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)). So *if* the OP wanted a WinForms application with a more accurate timer, a `System.Timers.Timer` is the way to go.

Comment: @JWLim - I thought about that, but with the timer in his/her code set to fire every 10 seconds, I thought the 55 millisecond resolution issue might be irrelevant.

Comment: @hatchet I agree, but it is still worth mentioning as we're not sure if that's the actual code the OP is going to use :) Besides, I think it's always a good thing to understand your options, lest you try to use them for things they were not designed for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set the [`SynchronizingObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.synchronizingobject.aspx) property of your timer to your form object.

```
timer.SynchronizingObject = this; // Synchronize the timer with this form UI
```

Relevant excerpt from the official documentation:

> When the Elapsed event is handled by a visual Windows Forms component,
>   such as a button, accessing the component through the system-thread
>   pool might result in an exception or just might not work. Avoid this
>   effect by setting SynchronizingObject to a Windows Forms component,
>   which causes the method that handles the Elapsed event to be called on
>   the same thread that the component was created on.

Comment: @Phil you're welcome, I'm glad it helped. I think you should tag your question with `[winforms]` btw (and perhaps `[timer]`), instead of `[multithreading]`.